# Convert a string to datetime2

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime2

Iam using an application that gets data through a communication protocol , and among data i get is  dates and i managed to form a string date out of that in this form :

```
"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.mmm"
```

I want to insert it in the database :

```
updateEvent_list = "INSERT INTO Events_List (date, Object,Event,IOA,ASDU) VALUES(@date, @event_object, @Event, @IOA, @ASDU)";
```

The `date column` is of `datetime2` type .

Question is : how can i convert the string i get into `datetime2`???

**EDIT :**

In fact i have two types of dates to insert : 
1) Frames that come with time tag : the ones that i convert their dates to string.
2) Frames that come without timetag : Iam using `DateTime date =DateTime.UtcNow`

Each of these work perfectly when they implemented independantly

Is there any solution that permits using both in the same program ??

Comment: Shouldn't this happen automaticly with the use of paramertized queries?

Comment: 'managed to form a string date out of that ' go further convert it to c# DateTime, and pass this date to sql cmd in convenient way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAST` :

```
"INSERT INTO Events_List (date, Object,Event,IOA,ASDU) VALUES(CAST(@date as DATETIME2), @event_object, @Event, @IOA, @ASDU)";
```